# Upgrading from ASP.NET 5 Beta 4 to Beta 5 - project.lock.json has old values

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have followed steps to upgrade from beta 4 to beta 5:

- Installed Visual Studio 2015 RTM
- From PowerShell run:  $env:DNX_FEED="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2"
- From PowerShell run: dnvm upgrade
- Changed  Global.json file:

  ```
  {
      "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
      "sdk": {
          "version": "1.0.0-beta5",
          "runtime": "coreclr",
          "architecture": "x86"
      }
  ```

  }
- Updated all packages in project.json to Beta 5:

  ```
  "dependencies": {
          "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta5",
          "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration": "1.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",
          "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta5",
          "System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" : "4.0.0-beta-23019",
          "System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
          "Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-beta5"
      },

  "commands": {
      "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
      "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
      "dnx451": { },
      "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
      "wwwroot",
      "node_modules",
      "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "bower_components",
      "**.xproj",
      "**.user",
      "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
      "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
  ```

  }

After all of this and few changes in code when I run NuGet package restore packages are not restored and my project.lock.json have old Beta4 paths.
See the picture attached.

[image: Error]

How to force project.lock.json to update?

Here is NuGet.config from %AppData%/NuGet/NuGet.Config:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2" />
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="NightlyBuilds" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>`

Comment: is your project.lock.json file read-only (possibly due to being checked in to TFS)?

Comment: @jltrem I have already checked that. It is not readonly and not added to Git.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your `NuGet.config` file (either at solution level or global) is pointing at the wrong NuGet feeds.

The `project.json.lock` file is updated when you do `dnu restore`. If that doesn't work, just delete the file and run `dnu restore`.

Comment: I have updated question with my NuGet.config. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Managed to fix issue. Problem was Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.UserSecrets. This package not exists anymore.